# String to 2D Array in PDF Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, pdf

I am including the AIRPORTS.txt file link as below, it is embedded in my PDF file as attachment.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/phr7rvmgegbrmpj/AIRPORTS.txt?dl=0

I have used below code to get myData to look like further below.

```
// Get the file stream object of the embedded file
var oFile = this.getDataObjectContents("AIRPORTS.txt");
// Convert to a file stream
var myData = util.stringFromStream(oFile, "utf-8");
```

which I think myData is a string consist of tabs and line breaks. Please correct me if I am wrong. It is not showing correctly here, but drop box link above should show correct format, it should be the "ADL" then tab then "ADELAIDE, AU" then a new line, then "AMS" then tab then "AMSTERDAM, NL", and so on. Screenshots further below.

```
ADL ADELAIDE, AU
AMS AMSTERDAM, NL
ATL ATLANTA, GA
BJS BEIJING, CN
BKK BANGKOK, TH
BLQ BOLOGNA, IT
BNE BRISBANE, AU
BOS BOSTON, MA
BWI BALTIMORE, MD
BWN BRUNEI, BN
CAN GUANGZHOU, CN
CLE CLEVELAND, OH
CLT CHARLOTTE, NC
CMH COLUMBUS, OH
CPH COPENHAGEN, DK
CPT CAPE TOWN, ZA
DCA WASHINGTON, DC
DEL DELHI, IN
DEN DENVER, CO
DFW FORT WORTH, TX
DLC DALIAN, CN
DRS DRESDEN, DE
DTW DETROIT, MI
EWR NEWARK, NJ
FLL FT. LAUDERDALE
FMO MUNSTER, DE
FRA FRANKFURT, DE
GUM GUAM, GU
HAM HAMBURG, DE
HGH HANGZHOU, CN
HKG HONG KONG, HK
HND HANEDA, JP
HNL HONOLULU, HI
IAD WASHINGTON, DC
IAH HOUSTON, TX
ICN INCHEON, KR
JED JEDDAH, SA
JFK NEW YORK, NY
KEF REYKJAVIK, IS
KUL KUALA LUMPUR,MY
LAS LAS VEGAS, NV
LAX LOS ANGELES , CA
LCK COLUMBUS, OH
LGA NEW YORK, NY
LHE LAHORE, PK
LHR LONDON, UK
LIS LISBON, PT
MCO ORLANDO, FL
MDW CHICAGO, IL
MEM MEMPHIS, TN
MIA MIAMI, FL
MNL MANILA, PH
MSP MINNEAPOLIS, MN
MSY NEW ORLEANS, LA
MUC MUNICH, DE
MXP MILAN, IT
NAN NADI, FJ
NRT NARITA, JP
OAK OAKLAND, CA
ORD CHICAGO, IL
PDX PORTLAND, OR
PEK BEIJING, CN
PHL PHILADELPHIA,PA
PHX PHOENIX, AZ
PIT PITTSBURGH, PA
PVG SHANGHAI, CN
RGN YANGON, MM
RUH RIYADH, SA
SAN SAN DIEGO, CA
SAT SAN ANTONIO, TX
SEA SEATTLE, WA
SFO SAN FRANCISCO
SGN HOCHIMINH CITY
SIN SINGAPORE, SG
STL ST. LOUIS, MO
SZX SHENZHEN, CN
TPA TAMPA, FL
TPE TAIPEI, TW
YUL MONTREAL, CA
YVR VANCOUVER, CA
YYZ TORONTO, CA
```

txt file screenshot
[txt file Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvtfy.png)
PDF Console Screenshot
[PDF Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7YTr.png)

My goal is to convert myData to a 2D array as below. Do I first "SPLIT" them into 1D array by line break, then somehow "SPLIT" the 1D array to a 2D array? What is the correct way of thinking and what code example should I be looking at? Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Would like to result in this 2D Array.

```
var myArray = [
  ["ADL", "ADELAIDE, AU"],
  ["AMS", "AMSTERDAM, NL"],
  ["ATL", "ATLANTA, GA"]
];
```

Sincerely

Alex

Answer (score 0):

You can first split on `\n` and than map and use match to match first word followed by space and than rest of the line.

```js
let str = `ADL ADELAIDE, AU
AMS AMSTERDAM, NL
ATL ATLANTA, GA
BJS BEIJING, CN
BKK BANGKOK, TH
BLQ BOLOGNA, IT
BNE BRISBANE, AU
BOS BOSTON, MA
BWI BALTIMORE, MD
BWN BRUNEI, BN
CAN GUANGZHOU, CN
CLE CLEVELAND, OH
CLT CHARLOTTE, NC
`

let op = str.split('\n').map(e=> e.match(/^\w+\s|[\w\W]+$/g))

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Thank you Code Maniac. I am using PDF JavaScript API, in which I think map is not available. Anyway to archive this within the PDF JavaScript API without getting involve of additional Runtime Environment?

Answer (score 0):

Split the first one by `\n` then map the resulting array and split each one by `\t` :

```
const result = str.split("\n").map(e => e.split("\t"));
```

```js
const str = `ADL ADELAIDE, AU
AMS AMSTERDAM, NL
ATL ATLANTA, GA
BJS BEIJING, CN
BKK BANGKOK, TH
BLQ BOLOGNA, IT
BNE BRISBANE, AU
BOS BOSTON, MA
BWI BALTIMORE, MD
BWN BRUNEI, BN
CAN GUANGZHOU, CN
CLE CLEVELAND, OH
CLT CHARLOTTE, NC
CMH COLUMBUS, OH
CPH COPENHAGEN, DK
CPT CAPE TOWN, ZA
DCA WASHINGTON, DC
DEL DELHI, IN
DEN DENVER, CO
DFW FORT WORTH, TX
DLC DALIAN, CN
DRS DRESDEN, DE
DTW DETROIT, MI
EWR NEWARK, NJ
FLL FT. LAUDERDALE
FMO MUNSTER, DE
FRA FRANKFURT, DE
GUM GUAM, GU
HAM HAMBURG, DE
HGH HANGZHOU, CN
HKG HONG KONG, HK
HND HANEDA, JP
HNL HONOLULU, HI
IAD WASHINGTON, DC
IAH HOUSTON, TX
ICN INCHEON, KR
JED JEDDAH, SA
JFK NEW YORK, NY
KEF REYKJAVIK, IS
KUL KUALA LUMPUR,MY
LAS LAS VEGAS, NV
LAX LOS ANGELES , CA
LCK COLUMBUS, OH
LGA NEW YORK, NY
LHE LAHORE, PK
LHR LONDON, UK
LIS LISBON, PT
MCO ORLANDO, FL
MDW CHICAGO, IL
MEM MEMPHIS, TN
MIA MIAMI, FL
MNL MANILA, PH
MSP MINNEAPOLIS, MN
MSY NEW ORLEANS, LA
MUC MUNICH, DE
MXP MILAN, IT
NAN NADI, FJ
NRT NARITA, JP
OAK OAKLAND, CA
ORD CHICAGO, IL
PDX PORTLAND, OR
PEK BEIJING, CN
PHL PHILADELPHIA,PA
PHX PHOENIX, AZ
PIT PITTSBURGH, PA
PVG SHANGHAI, CN
RGN YANGON, MM
RUH RIYADH, SA
SAN SAN DIEGO, CA
SAT SAN ANTONIO, TX
SEA SEATTLE, WA
SFO SAN FRANCISCO
SGN HOCHIMINH CITY
SIN SINGAPORE, SG
STL ST. LOUIS, MO
SZX SHENZHEN, CN
TPA TAMPA, FL
TPE TAIPEI, TW
YUL MONTREAL, CA
YVR VANCOUVER, CA
YYZ TORONTO, CA`

const result = str.split("\n").map(e => e.split("\t"));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you Taki. I am using PDF JavaScript API, in which I think map is not available. Anyway to archive this within the PDF JavaScript API without getting involve of additional Runtime Environment?

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned the possibility that `Array.map()` is not available on your environment, you can instead try a simple `for` loop to approach the same functionality that map offers.

**Example:**

```js
let input = `ADL ADELAIDE, AU
AMS AMSTERDAM, NL
ATL ATLANTA, GA`;

let res = input.split("\n");
console.log("Step 1) split by \\n: ", res);

for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++)
{
    res[i] = res[i].split("\t");
}

console.log("Step 2) split by \\t: ", res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Code Maniac @Taki @Shidersz

Thank you Guys. With your help and I have came up with below (not very professional written), this was tested in the PDF Javascript Console and working. I will get a little more hack on this. Sure will ask more questions.

```
// Get the file stream object of the embedded file
var oFile = this.getDataObjectContents("AIRPORTS.txt");
// Convert to a file stream
var myData = util.stringFromStream(oFile, "utf-8");
var myArray = myData.split("\n");
var r = myArray.length;
for (i = 0; i < r; i++){
myArray[i] = myArray[i].split("\t");
}
console.println(myArray);
```